# iOS App background services working when low-battery mode is ON

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process, batterylevel

Our application runs background services - however we noticed that these services stop working when the phone is in low-batter mode. 
How can we overcome this?

Comment: This is intention from the system, i dont think got anyway to overcome this

Comment: This would defeat the hole purpose of low battery mode. The user want to save battery power and you app should still be able to drain it? No, if the user selected to stop battery drain then it's up to the OS to kill what ever is drain the battery.